# PHP Facebook API Post on page's wall

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I know, this question was asked hundred times, but none of the given solutions works for me.
I'm trying to post on the wall of every page the current user owns. So, I first get the permissions to publish_actions, read_stream, manage_pages and offline_access. Then I check via /me/permissions, that the user really granted those permissions.

Then, I try to get all pages of the user and post on the wall of the page, if the user is the admin:

```
$accounts = $facebook->api("/me/accounts", "GET", array("access_token"=>$facebook->getAccessToken()));

$data = $accounts["data"];

foreach ($data as $page)
{
    if (isset($page["perms"]) && in_array("CREATE_CONTENT", $page["perms"])))
    {
        $facebook->api("/".$page["id"]."/feed", "POST", array("link"=>$link, "access_token"=>$page["access_token"]));
    }
}
```

But, posting on the wall of the page fails, with the well known error message

**Uncaught OAuthException: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action**

Any ideas? Where's my fault?

Comment: There must be so few legitimate reasons to do that :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can make the same call via the Graph API Explorer or cURL for one of the pages then your logic is right. So I would place a try/catch on the `page/id` call to see if a specific page is messing up the loop.

```
try {
    $facebook->api("/".$page["id"]."/feed", "POST", array("link"=>$link, "access_token"=>$page["access_token"]));
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e . " for: " .$page["id"] );
  }
}
```

Comment: I was successful using the Graph API Explorer. I generated an access_token with the necessary permissions, used /me/accounts to get the id and access_token of my page and posted on /me/feed using this data. But, I am not successful using cURL and/or the php-api. I have no clue, what's going on.

Comment: @user1742364 could you build the query in pure curl and show it in your question?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to post pure curl, but that's how I use it in PHP: [link](http://www.michaelholzhauser.de/fb.txt)

Comment: @user1742364 so does it not work for all pages using [your link](http://www.michaelholzhauser.de/fb.txt) or just a few?

Comment: Well, I tested it with one test user who owns two pages. and it doesn't work for any of those pages, although he is the admin of the pages and the app has all of the mentioned permissions.

Comment: @user1742364 Try this call in Terminal: `curl -F 'access_token=PAGE_TOKEN' -F 'message=test' 'https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/feed'`

Comment: Sorry for not replying so long, I was on vacation. The Result is the same as above: {"error":{"message":"(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action","type":"OAuthException","code":200}}

Comment: Reading the page's wall works perfectly. Isn't it enough to have manage_pages and publish_actions permissions?

Comment: @user1742364 could you run `curl 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions?access_token=PAGE_TOKEN`? for the same token that gave that error?

Comment: hm, it says {"error":{"message":"Unsupported get request.","type":"GraphMethodException","code":100}}     But /me/ is the wrong prefix, this page isn't owned by me, but by the user who gave me the permissions some day.

Comment: @user1742364 right my mistake, that shouldnt work @_@, do you have the user token that gave that page token?

Comment: @user1742364 Ok well I stumped, try `publish_stream` permissions? It's a superset. If that doesn't work, file a bug

Comment: Hah, it works :D I thought the superset relation between those two is vice versa. Another question: I read, that the page tokens expire sometime. Is it possible to expand them automatically? Or does the user have to give permissions again?

Comment: @user1742364 it's possible see Scenario 5 at https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

Comment: Okay, I will take a closer look at that. Thank you very much!